# View images for different dates/location in Google Earth Pro

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth, google-maps-api, google-earth-engine-python-api

I have been working with Google Earth Engine Code Editor/Google Maps API to view and analyze information surrounding specific points.

I am interested in analyzing these images from different dates. Back in October, I asked in StackOverflow if this could be done with Google Maps API, but it seems that there isn't much progress on this feature.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35824769

I know with Google Earth Pro it is possible to look historical imagery. However, manually doing this for many points is time consuming. Is it possible to do this in Earth Engine Code Editor or the Earth Engine Python API?

[image: ![Text](https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg)]

Comment: @user2856 Thank you for bringing this to my attention, I see the problem now. I just read the info on aerial orthoimagery and in order to use it, a subscription must be purchased. I will edit the question. My project does not necessarily need to download the images, I can work directly from GEE but information on tile date is important; I am wondering if at some point they will add this feature.

Comment: update - I did a little bit more search and with Google Maps API you can download aerial images but without the date information. If you need this data, you can contact the [Google Imagery Sales program](https://support.google.com/mapsdata/answer/6250079?hl=en&ref_topic=6250082). 
Now, I read [here](https://support.google.com/earth/thread/8014237?hl=en) that they usually take long to reply  so I reached out to Maxar technologies (company that takes the images). They directed me to one of their vendors and I am getting quotes at the moment.

Comment: Did you get any quotes or do you have an update on that?